# Export selected revision diff in tortoise SVN (both old and new files needed)

Tags: tortoisesvn

How can we export diff of selected revisions in Tortoise SVN with both the old file and new files in two seperate structures? 
For example, i want to isolate changes done to a branch, in a case where this branch is been modified by many users. So i wanted to select the necessary revisions and then do an export so that i get the changed files of those revisions as well as the old files too.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Open the "Repo-brower" (it shows up from the context menu of any versioned item). Find the first revision (pick the revision with the button on the top right corner and choose the location on the left panel), right click on the folder you want to computer and select "Mark for comparison". Repeat the steps for the second revision and select "Compare URLs". Now you have a list of the changed files. In order to export it, you have to highlight them all, right click and "Copy selection to clipboard". Paste in your favourite editor and you're done.

Yeah, it *should* be easier :)